# Ionic Framework - Uploading to Ionic View app, not getting latest javascript files, possibly cache still exists?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am self teaching Ionic framework i have loaded up the `ionic start myApp tabs` according to the Getting started page from Ionic framework (http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

Everything is good, up and running on my mac, can serve and can emulate. Now... when I used the `ionic upload` to the Ionic View app on my mobile its fine - everything as expected.

BUT when i changed something for example in the controller.js file:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

to `enableFriends:false`

and I `ionic upload` again, then i 'sync to latest' on the Ionic View app on my iphone... I am still getting the enableFriends:true (because the option was set to true - switch is green)

- Just to let you know, I `ionic build ios` before the `ionic upload`, I tried to delete the app in the Ionic View app on my phone and re uploaded it.

So I am suspecting that the controllers.js is cached... if yes.. how can i clear this cache??!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a solution - but not sure its the correct way but it works!

in the ionic.project file...

```
{
  "name": "someProject",
  "app_id": "2312n33"
}
```

delete the app_id!!!!

```
{
  "name": "someProject",
  "app_id": ""
}
```

this will generate a new app and it works! However if there is a better way to do this like clearing the cache (maybe there is the right way) - please post.

**UPDATE** - 20 May 2015

Ionic View App just fixed the caching issue where sync'ed changes weren't showing - in Version 1.0.6 Therefore this should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution worked. I think this is a serious bug.

Comment: Here is the issue reported for this: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-view-issues/issues/10

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that may be viewing this that may be having a problem with this in Ionic V2 apps not updating in the Ionic View App the process to execute is:

1. ionic serve
2. ionic upload
3. clear app data on view app

You'll notice that when you run ionic serve the build process executes which will update your files. Then you upload and your changes will be there. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this more?

try using the $ionicConfigProvider and set the cache to 0

code line would look like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp' ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
    //the rest of your Router information below here

});
```

[here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) is a link to the API where I found it

This may not be the best way, but is another option.